# pandas strictly increasing column group by

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, strict

```
dates=['2020-12-01','2020-12-03','2020-12-04', '2020-12-01','2020-12-03','2020-12-04']
symbols=['ABC','ABC','ABC','DEF','DEF','DEF']
v=[1,3,5,7,9,8]

df= pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'g':symbols, 'v':v})

         date    g  v
0  2020-12-01  ABC  1
1  2020-12-03  ABC  3
2  2020-12-04  ABC  5
3  2020-12-01  DEF  7
4  2020-12-03  DEF  9
5  2020-12-04  DEF  8

I want to create new dataframe group by 'g' and tell me whether it is strictly increasing or not.
For example, output
    g increasing
0    ABC 1
1    DEF 0
since ABC is always increasing whereas DEF is not.
```

I thought maybe I can use diff() and then select for names that have negative values. (These names I can exclude from list)
But I lose grouping column when I use this function:

```
df.groupby(by='g')['v'].diff()
0    NaN
1    2.0
2    2.0
3    NaN
4    2.0
5   -1.0
```

What is the best way to do this?

The following looks good but is NOT want I want (Since it returns true even if value stays the same)

```
>>> df.groupby(by='g')['v'].is_monotonic_increasing.reset_index()
     g      v
0  ABC   True
1  DEF  False
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by grouping by `g` and checking if it's increasing? You have multiple values for each value of `g`.

Comment: I am trying to find out whether or not ABC and DEF's corresponding column 'v' has been increasing.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check if is monotonic increasing and all the elements are unique. For this you could use pandas [is_monotonic_increasing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic_increasing.html) and [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html):

```
res = df.groupby('g', as_index=False)['v'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == len(x.unique()) and x.is_monotonic_increasing)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
g
ABC     True
DEF    False
Name: v, dtype: bool
```

As an alternative use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to check if all the values are unique:

```
res = df.groupby('g', as_index=False)['v'].apply(lambda x: (~x.duplicated()).all() and x.is_monotonic_increasing)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
     g      v
0  ABC   True
1  DEF  False
```

A third alternative is to use numpy and verify all the differences between consecutives elements are greater than 0:

```
res = df.groupby('g', as_index=False)['v'].apply(lambda x: np.all(np.diff(x) > 0))
```

Comment: i am not sure why but in both answers, I lose 'group' information.

Comment: What do you mean lose 'group' information?

Comment: I dont' have column 'g' along 'ABC','DEF' values

Comment: @StackOverflow Well I ran both answers with the example you provided and the output is the one shown. What version of pandas are you using? I'm using 1.1.4

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dani for answer. I had to make a small change to make 'g' column appear.

```
df.groupby('g', as_index=True)['v'].apply(lambda x: len(x) == len(x.unique()) and x.is_monotonic_increasing).reset_index()
```